# How to automate conversion of email of an acount on mail server to .eml file using java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, eml, mail-server

I have postfix email server configure on a linux machine. There is a email account e.g **xyz@emailaccount.com** is available on this mail server. 
    What exactly I want to do is Whatever email come to this email id should be converted to .eml file and this .eml file should be stored on a perticular location on hard disk. 
I want to automate this above process using java program. I thought that my java progam will run after certain interval of time using schedular and check for any new email. As soon as he found any new email he will
convert that email to .eml file and store this file on a perticular location. The mail coming to this email id mostly dont have any attachment to them. But still I want my program robust so that if unfortunately if some 
email comes with an attachment in that case the java program should not stop working.

Following are my questions that I want to ask to expert.

1. Is what am I expecting in above case is possible? and Whether is it possible in java?
2. As I checked on mail server the mail files for above email id have very long name and I dont found any extension to them. So How do I read mail in these files and convert them in .eml format using java.
3. If you know any tutorial related to above task or any reference link of code then please let me know about it.
4. I check on web and found that java have javamail api. Is this pacakage is helpfull for me to do above task or do I have to use any other api for java? If you know anything it it please let me know.

Please help me in above task friends.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's possible.
2. The simplest approach is to run an IMAP mail server to allow you to read the messages using JavaMail.  There are several IMAP mail servers available for Linux.
3. See the documentation on the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), especially the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).
4. Use JavaMail.